# How to stop CSS/HTML last drop down menu going missing on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

first post on here but a regular reader and user for various problems. I have this bit of code here to make a drop down menu. I have also attached my CSS code for said menu. The menus are working great other than one part. My last drop down menu with id "workwear" continues to the left as it should, this is great for high res screens however, for smaller screens the user can't see half of the menu not visible on their screen. What I would like to happen is the drop down to align to the right hand side of the workwear link rather than the left and continue out to the right

I have tried giving the 'workwear' ul a class and trying various things in my CSS I have researched however nothing seems to work.

Go easy on me if this a basic error and I appreciate any help you can give me.

```
<div id="ProdBar">

    <ul id="Prods">

        <li><a id="BuildingSupplies" href="BuildingSupplies.php" title="Building Supplies">   <span>Building Supplies</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/CementMortarPlaster.php">Cement, Mortar & Plaster</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Drainage.php">Drainage</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Gutterings.php">Gutterings</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/ScrewsFixings.php">Screws & Fixings</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/SiliconesSealants.php">Silicones & Sealants</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Adhesives.php">Adhesives & Pastes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a id="DoorsSecurity" href="DoorsSecurity.php" title="Doors And Security"><span>Doors And Security</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/Handles.php">Handles & Accessories</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/DoorLocks.php">Door Locks</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Padlocks.php">Padlocks</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


        <li><a id="Electrics" href="Electrics.php" title="Electrics"><span>Electrics</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/Bulbs.php">Bulbs & Strip Lighting</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Extensions.php">Extensions & Sockets</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/OutdoorLights.php">Outdoor Lighting</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Switches.php">Switches</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/WireCable.php">Wires & Cable</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a id="Flooring" href="Flooring.php" title="Flooring And Tiling"><span>Flooring & Tiling</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/Grips.php">Grips & Fittings</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/GroutAdhesives.php">Grouts & Adhesives</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a id="GardeningOutdoors" href="Gardening.php" title="Gardening And Outdoors"><span>Gardening & Outdoors</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/HoseFittings.php">Hoses & Fittings</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/FoodTreatment.php">Foods & Treatments</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/LawnCare.php">Lawn Care</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/PestControl.php">Pest Control</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/GardeningTools.php">Gardening Tools</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/ToolConsumables.php">Tool Consumables</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Weedkillers.php">Weedkillers & Cleaners</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/ExteriorWoodcare.php">Exterior Woodcare</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a id="HandPowerTools" href="HandPowerTools.php" title="Hand And Power Tools"><span>Hand & Power Tools</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/Drills.php">Drills</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Grinders.php">Grinders</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/HandTools.php">Hand Tools</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/PowerToolAccessories.php">Power Tool Accessories</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/SandersPlaners.php">Sanders & Planers</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/WorkTables.php">Work Tables</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a id="Homewares" href="Homewares.php" title="Homewares"><span>Homewares</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/Cleaning.php">Cleaning</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/CurtainFixtures.php">Curtain Fixtures</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Fireplace.php">Fireplace Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a id="PaintingDecorating" href="PaintingDecorating.php" title="Painting And Decorating"><span>Painting & Decorating</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/Adhesives.php">Adhesives & Pastes</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/DecoratingTools.php">Decorating Tools</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Emulsion.php">Emulsion</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/ExteriorPaints.php">Exterior Paints</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/FillerCaulk.php">Filler & Caulk</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/GlossSatinUndercoat.php">Gloss, Satin & Undercoat</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/SiliconesSealants.php">Silicone & Sealants</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/SpecialistPaint.php">Specialist Paints</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/StepsLadders.php">Steps & Ladders</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Woodcare.php">Woodcare</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a id="Plumbing" href="Plumbing.php" title="Plumbing"><span>Plumbing</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/PlumbingConsumables.php">Consumables</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/PlumbingFittings.php">Pipes & Fittings</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/PlumbingTools.php">Plumbing Tools</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/ShowerFittings.php">Shower Fittings</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/TapsPlugs.php">Taps & Plugs</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/ToiletAccessories.php">Toilet Accessories</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Venting.php">Venting</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a id="Workwear" href="Workwear.php" title="Workwear"><span>Workwear</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products/WorkwearConsumables.php">Consumables</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Coveralls.php">Coveralls</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/EarEyeProtection.php">Ear & Eye Protection</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Footwear.php">Footwear</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/JacketsFleeces.php">Jackets, Fleeces & Hoodies</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/SocksHatsGloves.php">Socks, Hats & Gloves</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Trousers.php">Trousers</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products/Tshirts.php">T Shirts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
#Prods, #Prods ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#Prods li {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
#Prods a {
    display: block;
}
#Prods li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: -999em;
    background:#C60001;
}
#Prods li ul.last {
    width: 200px;
}
#Prods li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#Prods li:hover li {
    float: none;
    font-family:"Century Gothic";
    font-size:14px;
}
#Prods li:hover li a {
    color: #FFF;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-left:6px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#Prods li li a:hover {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: #FFF;
}
#Prods li:hover ul, #Prods li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
    z-index:10;
}
```

You can [see it working on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmLfu1Lu/). Let me know if anymore info is needed and I will provide it.

Comment: The issue not only happens with `#workwear` but with all the menu items that end a line (you can see it by resizing the window). I may be wrong, but you may need some JavaScript to detect the position of the menu item and then display the dropdown to the right or the left depending on its width and the menu item position.

Comment: yeah alvaro, its not so much a problem with others just the last 1 (maybe 2). was hoping to avoid js and solve with some easy css but any help as to what js and how. not much experience in it

Answer (score 0):

One option is using the adjacent sibling selector (+) in your CSS, so some rules are only applied to the `ul` next to the `a` with id "workwear". For your specific case it would be:

```
#Prods li:hover a#Workwear + ul, #Prods li.sfhover a#Workwear + ul
```

Now that you have a rule for that particular dropdown, you can apply some CSS styling to it without affecting the rest.

For example, one thing that you could do is instead of displaying the dropdown at its position, translate it a bit to the left:

```
#Prods li:hover a#Workwear + ul, #Prods li.sfhover a#Workwear + ul {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/wmLfu1Lu/, and read more about the adjacent sibling selector here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors.